# CloudWatch - CPUUtilization metric

Tags: autoscaling, eucalyptus, cloudwatch

I'm able to work with the metric **GroupInServiceInstances** quietly. got after enable **euscale-enable-metrics-collection groupname -g 1minute**

But I can not work with the metric of **CPUUtilization** of the **AWS/EC2**, the alarm does not attend the metric, the state is only **INSUFFICIENT_DATA**. I noticed that when running the command **euscale-describe-metric-collection-types** shows nothing AWS/EC2, but only the AWS/ScalingGroup, see:

METRIC-COLLECTION-TYPE GroupDesiredCapacity

METRIC-COLLECTION-TYPE GroupInServiceInstances

METRIC-COLLECTION-TYPE GroupMaxSize

METRIC-COLLECTION-TYPE GroupMinSize

METRIC-COLLECTION-TYPE GroupPendingInstances

METRIC-COLLECTION-TYPE GroupTerminatingInstances

METRIC-COLLECTION-TYPE GroupTotalInstances

GRANULARITY-METRIC-TYPE 1minute

should be displayed:

METRIC-COLLECTION-TYPE       CPUUtilization

GRANULARITY-METRIC-TYPE    Percent

So, what I do to the alarm of the metric CPUUtilization AWS/EC2 work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The euca2ools euscale-* commands are for use with the Auto Scaling service, the euscale-describe-metric-collection-types command is the [DescribeMetricCollectionTypes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeMetricCollectionTypes.html) action, and only returns metrics for Auto Scaling.

To enable EC2 metrics in Eucalyptus you have to enable metrics collection for the instance ([euca-monitor-instances](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#euca2ools-guide/euca-monitor-instances.html)) and you should also ensure that when working with the CPUUtilization CloudWatch metric you specify the unit type of Percent.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try EucaLobo https://github.com/viglesiasce/EucaLobo?
I remember I had trouble with command line arguments at first.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. The alarm was creating from graphic interface when creating a command worked. I found that the GUI does not assign the unit (Percent) in alarm, which causes it to not collect the metrics percentage.